# PBEWITHHMACSHA512ANDAES_128 and Initialization Vector

Tags: java, encryption

I am working with the PBEWITHHMACSHA512ANDAES_128 excryption method from Java 8  If I initialize a KeySpec and Cipher object as follows:

```
SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithHmacSHA512AndAES_128");
KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(PASSWORD.toCharArray(), SALT.getBytes(), 4096, 128);
SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(),"PBEWithHmacSHA512AndAES_128" ); 
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWITHHMACSHA512ANDAES_128"); 
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);
```

I can encrypt and decrypt within the same execution of a Java program, however once the program completes, any data encrypted will be irretrievable.

My first assumption was that the JRE was selecting a random IV since it is required for block ciphers, but attempting to retrieve the IV with:

```
cipher.getParameters().getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class);
```

Yields an InvalidParameterSpecException.  The only way to get to decryptable data is to specify an IvParameterSpec wrapped by a PBEParameterSpec (passing an IvParameterSpec alone gives an InvalidAlgorithmParameterException).

Is passing the PBEParameterSpec the correct way to specify the IV and what would be the purpose in permitting users to not specify an IV when it is needed?

Thanks

Comment: Your post is missing the code where you construct the `PBEKeySpec`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default PBEWITHHMACSHA512ANDAES_128 uses CBC mode and PKCS5Padding.

You are right, according to the Java source code PBES2Core.java an random IV is used.

If you want to specify your own IV you have to do it this way (which uses an IV of null bytes):

```
    KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(PASSWORD.toCharArray());
    SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
    SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "PBEWithHmacSHA512AndAES_128");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWITHHMACSHA512ANDAES_128");
    IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16]);
    PBEParameterSpec pbeSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(SALT.getBytes(), 4096, iv);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret, pbeSpec);
```